# Change package directory in eclipse dark mode to be black

Tags: eclipse

How do i change the part in the image below to be black instead of white?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to Eclipse 2018-09 (4.9) or higher.

See:

- [Eclipse 4.9 - New and Noteworthy - Improved Breadcrumb for Dark theme](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.9/jdt.php#breadcrumb-dark)
- [Video that shows this improvement](https://youtu.be/13dka9ut-xs?t=64)